# Get a PostgreSQL client connected to MariaDB

Tags: mysql, postgresql, mariadb

I have a customer who uses a postgres client but wants access to the data contained in my MariaDB (in real-time, not a one-time copy). The customer only has the ability to use a postgres client, not any other protocol, nor can they install any extra tools. However, I am flexible and can install any needed tools, but I don't want to migrate permanently from MariaDB to PostgreSQL.

Other than [MySQL Foreign Data Wrapper for PostgreSQL](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw), are there any tools which can help me?

Comment: tell them no?  just a suggestion

Comment: I would delete your question, and post on the StackExchange Database Administrators site instead.  Otherwise others will vote to close before you do.

Comment: The Foreign Data Wrapper solution is all I can think of too. This is a very odd request. IMO, you should just move to PostgreSQL if they want to use PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Even the MySQL FDW will not help you, as it requires a Postgres server to run on. With just the Postgres client there is no way to access a MySQL database.

Comment: I can install the postgres server on my end, so MySQL FDW is a possibility. I just wanted to know if there are other options. thx